# How to translate jQuery function into native javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I have an issue with my homework. Before i explain this, i want to apologize about my english.
So, i try to make a chat in node.js. I pick a litle code from a website "https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/1056721-des-applications-ultra-rapides-avec-node-js/1057959-tp-le-super-chat".
It works well. The chat use an input text to send messages.

My problem is: this chat use a jQuery librairies and it's so old that i want to translate jQuery's functions into native javascript. I already success to translate 3 of them. One is still resist.

```
$('#formulaire_chat').submit(function () {
    var message = $('#message').val();
    socket.emit('message', message); // Send the message to others clients
    insereMessage(pseudo, message); // Also post the message on our page
    $('#message').val('').focus(); // Empty the Chat area and put the focus back on
    return false; // Allows you to block the "classic" sending of the form
});
```

i try to turn this into this:

```
document.getElementById('formulaire_chat').submit(function () {
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    socket.emit('message', message); // Send the message to others clients
    insereMessage(pseudo, message); // Also post the message on our page
    document.getElementById('message').value = ' ';
    document.getElementById('message').focus();
    return false; // Allows you to block the "classic" sending of the form
});
```

When i use the "translate" function i get the error "Cannot POST /"
I try to manipulate all the line, one by one, to find where it blocks.
But despite my hours of works it's not working yet.
I'm learning code and i'm a beginner so don't judge me please.

Comment: what is the line of error ?

Comment: Is the question, i think the problem is the first line, in fact i don't really know. Just my application is working without the function, so i can't send message. But as soon as implemented my code it doesn't work. Since the first line. I think that was a chain problem, so i try to explore this way. But without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try .addEventListener or .onsubmit() or (onsubmit="submitFunction()" on html of form tag)

```
document.getElementById('formulaire_chat').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    socket.emit('message', message); // Send the message to others clients
    insereMessage(pseudo, message); // Also post the message on our page
    document.getElementById('message').value = ' ';
    document.getElementById('message').focus();
    return false; // Allows you to block the "classic" sending of the form
});
```

Comment: okay, thanks a lot i try all your solutions and the ".onsubmit()" and the ".addEventListener('submit', function(evt)" are working. It still an issue yet after this but it fix some bug. In fact now i can see the message "pop" in the area provided for messages. And then, a few miliseconde after this, the "cannot /POST" error arrives. So i think i will work on it but thanks a lots to point my mistake !

Answer (score 0):

it's not .submit() but .onsubmit()

Comment: Thanks i didn't see this mistake, i'm a beginner in javascript so i don't have all the syntax. After hours to try to make link between jQuery and native language i didn't see the "onsubmit()" syntax.

Comment: it's all right everybody is once a beginner ! or even twice : there are so many interesting things to learn ! :-) for instance : I know nothing about node.js Tu pourrais être mon professeur lol

Comment: do you know : http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ this site is just what you need !

Comment: Yeah i took a look on this website. It help a lot when you need to use JS native and got a jQuery code.